# Ubuntu UI texts not showing properly

Tags: 14.04, gui

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS from the [Ubuntu page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) 3 days ago but now the UI texts is broken as you can see in this [image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2lkxj4o&s=8#.VWaYkjX8s8o)

Do you have any idea how to solve this? and what is causing it?

Comment: every text in every window is incomplete. If I right click in any window the context menu text is incomplete. the browser tabs text is incomplete and just showing some few letters.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. I just installed some updates that I were skipping all the time. Now everything is fine.